# Order of execution of dealloc in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a class with attribute MemberClass. In setup method, I allocate and addObserver to MemberClass.

```
@interface ParentClass()
    MemberClass *_member;
@end

@implementation ParentClass

-(void)dealloc
{
   if (_member)
   {   [_member removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"key" context:nil];
        _member = nil;
   }
}

-(void)setup
{
   _member = [[MemberClass alloc] init];
   [_member addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"key" option:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:context];
}
@end
```

My question is ParentClass's dealloc() always being called before MemberClass 's dealloc() being called? And when will MemberClass's dealloc() being called?

Update:
I am getting an exception 
"class MemberClass's was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it". From the code, I don't see how that is possible. Since ParentClass always removeObserver in dealloc().

Comment: The MemberClass object does not see its reference count go to zero (making it eligible for deallocation) until after the `_member = nil;` statement is executed in `dealloc`.  And `dealloc` is not executed until the ParentClass object's reference count has gone to zero.  (In ARC the reference count may not be literally manipulated that way, but the sense is the same.)

Comment: Check to make sure that `-[setup]` is not being (unintentionally) called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance that `_member` references will be deallocated when there are no more references to the instance.

If the `MemberClass` instance is only kept by the associated `ParentClass` instance, then as your code is written, the `ParentClass` `dealloc` will be called before the `MemberClass` `dealloc` is called.

This assumes that by the time `ParentClass dealloc` is called, the only reference to the `MemberClass` instance is the instance of `ParentClass` being deallocated.

What you are doing appears correct. Your `ParentClass` code is properly managing the `MemberClass` instance and properly cleaning up the observer.

The call to `_member = nil` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

An object is deallocated when there are no longer any strong references to it.

The `ParentClass` instance has a strong reference to `_member`.

`ParentClass`'s `dealloc` method will therefore always be called before `MemberClass`'s `dealloc` method.

`_member` won't be deallocated until the parent class is deallocated, which doesn't happen until after `ParentClass`'s `dealloc` method returns.